# make specific column only new Dataframe panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let say I have

sim_users

```
critic  critic  Claudia Puig    Gene Seymour    Jack Matthews   Lisa Rose   Mick LaSalle    Toby
0   Claudia Puig    1.000000    0.314970    0.028571    0.566947    0.566947    0.893405
1   Gene Seymour    0.314970    1.000000    0.963796    0.396059    0.411765    0.381246
2   Jack Matthews   0.028571    0.963796    1.000000    0.747018    0.211289    0.662849
3   Lisa Rose   0.566947    0.396059    0.747018    1.000000    0.594089    0.991241
4   Mick LaSalle    0.566947    0.411765    0.211289    0.594089    1.000000    0.924473
5   Toby    0.893405    0.381246    0.662849    0.991241    0.924473    1.000000
```

and If I want to make  new framework only critic and Toby. 
how this accomplished with pandas?
i tried to use iloc

```
sim_usersToby=sim_users.iloc[:,6:7]
```

but not sure how to combine two different column together

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try this :

```
sim_usersToby = sim_users.ix[:, ["critic", "Toby"]]
```

for your comment :

```
sim_usersToby['ClaudiaGene'] = sim_users["Claudia Puig"] * sim_users["Gene Seymour"]
```

Comment: do you know make new column  like   new column  = Claudia Puig * Gene Seymour??

Comment: claudia_gene = sim_users["Claudia Puig"] * sim_users["Gene Seymour"]

Comment: and how to append it to the original dataframework with name 'sum;'?

Comment: sim_users["sum;"] = sim_users["Claudia Puig"] * sim_users["Gene Seymour"]